# How to create a new column for the first non-NA group by factors?

Tags: r

```
Firms    Time     X      Initial X
 1        1        100    100
 1        2        50     100
 1        3        70     100
 2        1        NA     40
 2        2        40     40
 2        3        60     40
 3        1        30     30
 3        2        40     30
 3        3        80     30
 4        1        NA     90
 4        2        NA     90
 4        3        90     90
```

I want to create a column for each firm. The new column `Initial X` is the first non-NA `X` at starting year.

Comment: `library(dplyr); df1 %>% group_by(Firms) %>% mutate(newX = X[!is.na(X)][1])`

Comment: Thanks @akrun, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(data.table)

DT <- setDT(df1)
DT[,InitialX := .SD[!is.na(X),X][1],by = Firms]
```

Here with data table: .SD select de wole data.table within each broup defined by by = Firms. You select in this data table the non NA of X (.SD[!is.na(X),X]) and take the first element ([1]). You assign it to InitialX, and it gives you what you want:

```
    Firms Time   X InitialX
 1:     1    1 100      100
 2:     1    2  50      100
 3:     1    3  70      100
 4:     2    1  NA       40
 5:     2    2  40       40
 6:     2    3  60       40
 7:     3    1  30       30
 8:     3    2  40       30
 9:     3    3  80       30
10:     4    1  NA       90
11:     4    2  NA       90
12:     4    3  90       90
```

It is akrun equivalent answer but with data table

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution:

```
initial <- function(x) c(na.omit(x), NA_real_)[1]
transform(DF, Initial_X = ave(X, Firms, FUN = initial))
```

Alternately we could replace `initial` with any of these (the last is not base):

```
initial <- function(x) sort(x, na.last = TRUE)[1]

initial <- function(x) if (all(is.na(x))) NA_real_ else na.omit(x)[1]

library(zoo)
initial <- function(x) na.locf0(x, fromLast = TRUE)[1]
```

**Note:** The input `DF` in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "
Firms    Time     X      Initial_X
 1        1        100    100
 1        2        50     100
 1        3        70     100
 2        1        NA     40
 2        2        40     40
 2        3        60     40
 3        1        30     30
 3        2        40     30
 3        3        80     30
 4        1        NA     90
 4        2        NA     90
 4        3        90     90"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)[1:3] # retain 1st 3 cols only
```